# Proper design for a table with subset of columns null per row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I will start my question with the abstract case and then I will also give a concrete example in case it helps.
Assuming I have a tableX with columns A,B,C,D,E,F.
A,B,F are required.
Now we can have a record with C,D populated (so E is null) or a record with E populated (so C,D are null).
Is this table normalized or properly designed? I am not sure if this relations/expectations among these columns as I described should be "captured" differently.
Example:
A table to be used by a message processor where either the actual msg to get/process is stored in column E OR the url and the protocol to fetch the message to process are stored in columns C and D

Answer (score 2):

Normally tables that store `Class Hierarchy` (super class and sub-classes together) require a separate `discriminator` column.  In your case each of the three columns - C,D or E - can be used as such, so an additional column is required.

Such data organization offers best performance for simple queries.

If you split it into 3 separate tables (super class and its two sub-classes) you will get a normalized model. I believe in your case it does not make sense, as long as you have just these three nullable columns.

If your example is a simplified presentation of your real data model and your sub-classes differ substantially, then normalization will be more economical in storage space and offer faster execution for queries that rely solely on super class data.

Comment: `an additional column is required.` You mean an extra column in the same table?

Comment: Yes. If in your example there were records where **all three** fields - C, D and E - are null, you would be needing an additional column to separate the two sub-classes.

Comment: In `ORM` terminology your case is defined as `Single Table Inheritance`.  If this is of interest for you, just *google* it.

Answer (score 1):

The table is probably not properly normalized.  It sounds like there are two types of entities being stored in the table -- the A,B,C,D,F entity and the A,B,E,F entity.

Does this make the schema bad?  Probably not.  Relational databases use primary keys to connect one table to another.  If other tables can connect to either type of entity, then it makes sense to store them in a single table.  This allows one single key to connect them.  You could, of course, introduce a three table schema (one for each subentity and one for the parent entity).  This could be overkill when the entities are really quite similar.

Your example is a fine example.  This sounds like a control table for a process that can do one of two things.  It makes sense that different columns are used for each type processing.